# (Android) White piano key overlap black key when clicked

Tags: android, xml, frontend, android-constraintlayout

I made piano keyboard with ConstraintLayout and it looks good until i press white key. It overlap black key and turn back if press black key. The onClick works as expected, the keys play their own sounds. How to solve the problem? Tried `android:translationZ`, `android:elevation` - no effect. Maybe i need to change ui button reaction on click? But i don't know how to. And one more newbie question: Can i do buttons with no `<Button>` tag, maybe  `<View>` etc.?

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".PianoKeyboard">
    <!-- Guidelines -->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_leftKeysguideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.15" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_blackKeysguideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.42" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_topKeysguideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.2" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_botKeysguideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.8" />

    <!-- Piano white keys -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_c2_button"
        android:onClick="onClickC2"
        style="@style/white_keys"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_d2_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_piano_leftKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_topKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_d2_button"
        android:onClick="onClickD2"
        style="@style/white_keys"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_e2_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_piano_leftKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_piano_c2_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_e2_button"
        android:onClick="onClickE2"
        style="@style/white_keys"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_botKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_piano_leftKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_piano_d2_button" />

    <!-- Piano black keys -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_c2d_button"
        style="@style/black_keys"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:onClick="onClickC2D"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_d2_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_piano_blackKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_piano_c2_button"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/activity_piano_d2d_button"
        android:onClick="onClickD2D"
        style="@style/black_keys"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/activity_piano_e2_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_piano_blackKeysguideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_piano_d2_button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
    <style name="white_keys" parent="">
        <item name="android:insetBottom">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">2dp</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/white_keys</item>
    </style>

    <style name="black_keys" parent="">
        <item name="android:insetBottom">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:insetTop">2dp</item>
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/black_keys</item>
        <item name="layout_constraintHeight_percent">0.06</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: If you mean that you want to disable the elevation animation altogether, you can set `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` on the `<Button>`s. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "buttons with no tag".

Comment: @MikeM. In HTML i can use <div> instead of <button> and set onClick on it. Can i do the same in Android? Maybe there are some rules where button is <button> and div is <div> and it's better don't retreat from this.

Comment: You can set an `OnClickListener` on any kind of `View`. You could use just plain `<View>`s instead of `<Button>`s, if you want.

Comment: @MikeM. `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` it works, thank you very much. But it doesn't work if i add it in my `<style>` file like this `<item name="android:stateListAnimator">"@null"</item>`

Comment: No problem! The style item doesn't use quotes in the value: `<item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>`.

Comment: @MikeM. with no quotes was my first try, doesn't work anyway

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Are you getting a build error? Or do you mean it just doesn't work at runtime?

Comment: @MikeM. No any errors. I did it two ways: 1. Add string `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` on the `<Button>` in activity xml file. 2. Add `<item>` in `<styles>` file. First way works good, the second way doesn't work

Comment: @MikeM. maybe i need to set any `parent=''` in my `<style>` tag

Comment: @MikeM. Okay, the site started to swear for a lot of comments. I think I'll figure it out myself, thanks again, good luck.

Comment: Not necessarily. Those few attributes are just tacked onto styles from a couple of other places, and that's where the default animator value is coming from anyway. I don't recall there being anything special about that particular attribute, but I can't check anything right this minute. I'll spin up a test project when I get a chance, after a bit. (Don't worry about the site warning too much. You can delete old ones to stop it complaining, if you want.)

Comment: @MikeM. I have another styles file `v29\styles.xml` and there it works. I guess now i need to add all my changes in both these files?

Comment: Short answer, yes, if you're keeping those separate styles, 'cause on Android Pie and above, it's only the `v29` one that applies. I should also mention that if you switch to `<View>`s, you won't need that `stateListAnimator` setting at all, 'cause plain `View`s won't have that set, by default. It's mostly `Button`s that use that.